# How can I select "document.write", etc. in jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select "document.write", etc. in jQuery or Javascript? Sample;

```
<script> document.write("Taha"); </script>
```

How can I grab `document.write` in this code?

Comment: Could you be more specific? How do you want to select it? Why? It  is hard to understand.

Comment: please explain in detail what you mean by "select" ?

Comment: why do you want to get the `document.write` although it is not recommended to use. instead you can use `innerHTML`  js method.

Comment: I want to grab and change document.write code. It is my scholl project. My project will grab and change some javascript codes. I will make it as a extension.

Answer (score 0):

Code within the script block cannot be "selected" in the jQuery sense of the word. If you wish to grab the script block, you can select a  element more or less the same as you can any other element. You could then grab the script's text property, and then process it from there. A naive example would be:

```
<script id="theScriptIWant"> document.write("Taha"); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scriptText = $("#theScriptIWant").text();
    var scriptLines = scriptText.split("\n");
    var codeLines = [];
    for (var i=0; i < scriptLines.length; i++) {
        if (scriptLines[i] == "")
            continue;
        codeLines = codeLines.concat(scriptLines[i].split(";"));
    }
    // Do something with each codeline (like check if it contains your document.write("tada") ) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just wrap your text in a `span` with an ID?
Then you could retrieve the text using the `innerText` property

```
<script> document.write('<span id="written">Taha</span>') </script>
<script>
    document.getElementById('written').innerText;
</script>
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/yodaqanuqe/2/edit?js,output)

** Edit **

Additional example based on html elements:

HTML elements can be retrieved with the `getElementsByTagName` which will retrieve all elements of a particular type as an `HTMLCollection`. You can then loop through all the elements in this collection and get the `innerText` property.

There are other options that can be used such as `getElementsByClassName` which will retrieve all elements with a certain CSS class.

In this example, I'm using `document.write` to write 3 spans (without ids) and then retrieve them as described above.

```
<script> document.write('<span>Taha First</span>') </script>
<script> document.write('<span>Taha Second</span>') </script>
<script> document.write('<span>Taha Third</span>') </script>
<script>

    var htmlColl = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i=0; i< htmlColl.length; i++){
        alert(htmlColl[i].innerText);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean element? like the `span` or do you mean the `name attribute`?

Comment: Yes. Like `script` or `p`.

Comment: Thank you so much jasonscript. So how can I change document.write to <!--document.write ? I want to disable it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to disable the `document.write` methods, finding the html it writes is too late